# evaluating buffer in emacs python-mode on remote host

Tags: python, emacs

I'm using emacs23 with tramp to modify python scripts on a remote host.
I found that when I start the python shell within emacs it starts up 
python on the remote host.

My problem is that when I then try to call python-send-buffer via C-c C-c it comes up with the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in ?
>   ImportError: No module named emacs
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in ?
>   NameError: name 'emacs' is not defined

Now, I must admit that I don't really know what's going on here. Is there a way for me to configure emacs so that I can evaluate the buffer on the remote host?

Many thanks.

Edit: I've followed eichin's advice and re-implemented python-send-region. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not without writing some missing elisp code.

Long version: In `python.el`, `run-python` adds `data-directory` (which on my Ubuntu 10.10 box is `/usr/share/emacs/23.1/etc/` ) to `$PYTHONPATH`, specifically so that it can find `emacs.py` (as supplied by the local emacs distribution.)  Then it does a `(python-send-string "import emacs")` and expects it to work...

It looks like the `defadvice` wrappers that `tramp` uses don't actually pass `PYTHONPATH`, so this doesn't work even if you have the matching emacs version on the remote system.

If you `M-x customize-variable RET tramp-remote-process-environment RET`
then hit one of the `INS` buttons and add `PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/emacs/23.1/etc` then hit `STATE` and set it to "current session" (just to test it, or "save for future sessions" if it works for you) it *almost* works - the complaint goes away, in any case, because the remote python can now find the remote `emacs.py`.  If you now go back to the original question, doing `python-send-buffer`, you just run into a different error: `No such file or directory: '/tmp/py24574XdA'` because `python-mode` just stuffs the content into a temporary file and tells the python subprocess to load that.

You'd have to change `python-send-region` (the other functions call it) and particularly the way it uses `make-temp-file` to be tramp-aware - there's even a `tramp-make-tramp-temp-file` you could probably build upon.  (Be sure to post it if you do...)

Comment: Many thanks. I've posted my implementation of python-send-region below and it seems to work.

Comment: Any word if this has been fixed in the last 4 years? It'd be great if the updated answer is, "it just works now".

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently trying to to get my unregistered question merged with this account, after which I'll be able to accept eichin's answer and edit my post to include my solution.

I followed eichin's suggestion and copied the emacs2.py emacs3.py and emacs.py files to the remote host and added their directory to PYTHONPATH in the tramp-remote-process-environment variable.

I then reimplemented the python-send-buffer function in my .emacs

```
(require 'python)

(defun python-send-region (start end)
  "Send the region to the inferior Python process."

  (interactive "r")

  (let* ((loc_name)
     (f (if (file-remote-p default-directory)
        (let* ((con (tramp-dissect-file-name default-directory)))
          (setq loc_name (tramp-make-tramp-temp-file con))
          (concat "/"
              (tramp-file-name-method con) ":"
              (tramp-file-name-user con) "@"
              (tramp-file-name-host con) ":"
              loc_name
              ))
          (setq loc_name (make-temp-file "py"))))
     (command (format "emacs.eexecfile(%S)" loc_name))
     (orig-start (copy-marker start)))
    (save-excursion
      (let ((curbuf (current-buffer))
        (tempbuf (get-buffer-create "*python_temp*")))
    (set-buffer tempbuf)
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (insert-buffer-substring curbuf start end)
    (python-mode)
    (when (save-excursion 
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (/= 0 (current-indentation)))
      (python-shift-left (point-min) (point-max)))
    (write-region nil nil f nil 'nomsg))

    (python-send-command command)
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer (python-proc))
      ;; Tell compile.el to redirect error locations in file `f' to
      ;; positions past marker `orig-start'.  It has to be done *after*
      ;; `python-send-command''s call to `compilation-forget-errors'.
      (compilation-fake-loc orig-start f)))
))
```

I essentially copy the region into a new buffer, adjust the indentation and then write it into a temporary file, created with tramp-make-tramp-temp-file or make-temp-file, depending on whether the visited file is remote or local.

I had some problems with tramp-handle-write-region, which didn't seem to accept a string as a first argument, which is why I did all the formatting in a separate buffer first.

Let me know if there are still any problems with the code, but this is my first attempt at elisp coding, so please be gentle.

Comment: I tried the above and got the following error: "ad-Orig-error: Invalid file-name". Any pointers?